# Submitting Canada visa application for Holiday in Canada

Tags: visas, canada, paperwork, applications, nigerian-citizens

How possible is this ?  I have an invitation For canada, but can this be possible , going to submit a TRV application without Invitation? i.e I just book a hotel and have enough bank statements balances etc, Say i am going for just a holiday?
I am from Nigeria

Answer (score 1):

A letter of invitation is not mandatory - if you don’t have personal connections in Canada then you can’t supply one. What is necessary, in common with visitor visas to pretty much any destination, is being able to convince an immigration officer that you have ties—such as a job, home, financial assets or family—that will take you back to your home country at the end of your visit
and that you have enough money for your stay.

https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/eligibility.html